# Passing Javascript variable to C# function aspx and return from it to aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can I pass the variable to c# function?.
Suppose that:

```
<script>

    var myValue;

    function setValue(idriga) {
        myValue = idriga;
    }

    function getValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

</script>
```

This is a script that set and get value. How can i pass the `myValue` value to a c# function code behind without calling aspx page and passing parameters but passing from aspx to aspx.cs and the from aspx.cs to aspx to show value returned from c# method (example search value into db and return other value?)

My function c# is:

```
protected string SearchUserByGuid(Guid area) {
    return (from us in contextDB.AREAS
            where us.ID_AREAS == area
            select us.USER_NAME).Single();
}
```

Comment: you want do this on first page load? or dynamicaly

Comment: ehm dynamically i think.. thanks

Comment: Are you try with HiddenField ?

Comment: @user1828965 so use `webmethod`, `GenericHandlers` etc as said @Roy

Comment: Grundy i have used the [WebMethod] before method. But when i call it i can't pass variable to c# function.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for passing variable to your WebMethod you can use ajax. With Jquery it  it will be something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/SearchUserByGuid",
    data:JSON.stringify({area: 'YourValueToPass'}),
    success: function (dt) { alert(dt);}, //all Ok
    error: function () { alert('error'); } // some error
});
```

also your WebMethod will be public static, so change your method declaration like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SearchUserByGuid(Guid area) {
    return (from us in contextDB.AREAS
        where us.ID_AREAS == area
        select us.USER_NAME).Single();
}
```

Comment: What's the json value?

Comment: `{area: 'YourValueToPass'}` - object with field that have same name that parameter name in your webmethod, `'YourValueToPass'` - value that you want pass to webmethod

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you are asking for, but if I do, it's **not possible**.

What you *can* do is call a server-side method from JavaScript using AJAX. This server-side method can be a static `[WebMethod]` or a WebAPI method (if you use ASP.NET MVC or if you have a WebAPI Project).

For more about calling WebMethods with AJAX (and jQuery): http://deebujacob.blogspot.be/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html

For more about Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: i'm reading the articles now! thanks for answering Roy. I will mark as answer when i'm sure it's a working answer for me. Tjanks again